# Caching problem: Why does the pager of my pages module not work?

Tags: 7, views, caching, paging

I am using the pages module in combination with the view module on the [front page of my website](https://www.gelaendespiele.ch).
This worked until recently, when my pager started to behave strangely.
The pager does not work anymore and always shows the same items for all the different pages according to the first page that is accessed after clearing internal drupal cache.

Examples: If internal drupal cache is cleared and the next session on my website starts on `?page=6`, the correct items are displayed for page 6. However if any other user then visits the front page/page 1 or any user clicks on any page, it will always be displayed like page 6 as well regardless of page number.

If I clear drupal cache and start on `?page=2`, I also have items from page 2 on all the other pages.

This seems to be a caching issue. It is true I have tried to optimize cachinge quite a bit and e. g. set **browser caching for pages**. However I **disabled that again** as well as caching of views and still the error occures. Somehow I feel like this might even be a bug and my reverse to not caching pages anymore does not work?

Of course I cleared internal drupal cache after each change.
Also the described paging error does not occure in the preview function of that module in the backend section. There the paging works just fine.

Additional information that could be an issue: Another module I have tried is "Boost" but I have disabled this module now.
Same goes for AdvAgg, in this case, however, I am pretty sure AdvAgg is not the problem because I have used it for a long time and did not have the issue.

Can you help me in this?

Comment: If this a drupal 7 question its better to add appropriate tag.

Comment: Are you display the view in a block? Then check if you have block caching enabled. In order to track down the error I would first of all disable all caches under `admin/config/development/performance` and see if the error goes away - if it does then indeed you have a cache related problem.

Comment: Cache is disabled and cleared ([Screenshot](https://imgur.com/locE0cK)). The view is loaded as page not as a block. Caching is disabled both for the view (advanced settings) and the page (from page module).